# What is proper way to store links of uploaded files using multer?

Tags: node.js, multer

After multile files are uploaded using multer, it gives me paths of each files like:

```
"photo" : [ 
        "public/uploads/1/store/aa17c810-0178-11ea-adf6-c9fa892f6902.png",
...
    ],
```

And this is accessible in a url, "http://localhost:3000/public/uploads/1/store/aa17c810-0178-11ea-adf6-c9fa892f6902.png".

But in React (or maybe any frontend), I had to put slash to the front of this url, like following (assume imageUrl has value "public/uploads/1/store/aa17c810-0178-11ea-adf6-c9fa892f6902.png":

```
<div>
       <img src={"/" + imageUrl} />
 </div>
```

If I don't put "/" to front, path is referred as relative path.

If I use that imageUrl without attaching "/" to the head of that img src, the problem is that in the page url like http://localhost:3000/product, it will try to check the path relatively and then get the file from "http://localhost:3000/product/public/uploads/1/store/aa17c810-0178-11ea-adf6-c9fa892f6902.png", where the file doesn't exists.

So my question is that should I put "/" to each file path that multer returns, then store it to mongodb?

or should I just put "/" everytime I use img tag?

what is the the most standard preferred way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd save the whole path including the first slash in MongoDB because a path starting with "/" kinda indicates it starts at the root. (In this case, the root of your project.)

Also, the potential performance gain in using this:

```
<div>
    <img src={imageUrl} />
</div>
```

Instead of that:

```
<div>
    <img src={ "/" + imageUrl} />
</div>
```

Is negligible if not inexistent, But the code looks a tiny bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

When i used multer i was also getting these kind of problems.I think in your case just store / using multer  in each path in mongodb